# Generate axis scale

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project where I need to calculate some scale for slider. The user can define min, max and step.
You can find the code below:

```
var j = Math.round(cfg.max / cfg.step);
var l = (containerWidth / (j - 1));
for (var i = 0; i < j; i++) {
  s.push('<span style="left:');
  s.push(l * i);
  s.push('px">');
  s.push(cfg.step * (i + 1));
  s.push('</span>');
}

Example: min=1 max=12 step=3
Generated scale: 3  6  9  12
Slider ticks:    1 4 7 10 12
```

I would like to know how I can generate ticks for slider.

Comment: Hi, I don't understand what the question is, drawing the ticks on screen or calculating them?

Comment: Is your question "Calculate *n* evenly-spaced integer ticks for an arbitrary range with min *x* and max *y* where *x* and *y* are integers"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your question can be rephrased like this:

> Calculate *n* ticks for an arbitrary range with min *x* and max *y*

Then we can adapt the [linear tick function from D3.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/scale/linear.js#L87):

```
function calculateTicks(min, max, tickCount) {
    var span = max - min,
        step = Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log(span / tickCount) / Math.LN10)),
        err = tickCount / span * step;

    // Filter ticks to get closer to the desired count.
    if (err <= .15) step *= 10;
    else if (err <= .35) step *= 5;
    else if (err <= .75) step *= 2;

    // Round start and stop values to step interval.
    var tstart = Math.ceil(min / step) * step,
        tstop = Math.floor(max / step) * step + step * .5,
        ticks = [];

    // now generate ticks
    for (i=tstart; i < tstop; i += step) {
        ticks.push(i);  
    } 
    return ticks;
}
```

This isn't exactly to your specifications - it generates a set of nicely-rounded ticks, often 1-2 more or fewer than `tickCount`:

```
calculateTicks(1, 12, 5); // [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
calculateTicks(0, 12, 4); // [0, 5, 10]
```

It's hard to come to an optimum solution here, but I think the D3 approach does it relatively well - in my opinion, I'd rather have the ticks `2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12` for a range `1-12` than the ticks `1, 4, 7, 10, 12` that you suggest.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/B3EM4/

Comment: There's a defined var `x` that's not used. Besides that it's just great.

Comment: Thanks @claudiomedina - fixed. :)